# How to create dynamic drop downs in excel based on another cell

Tags: excel, list

For example, lets say I have 2 tables.  Table A is Provinces while Table B is Cities.

I don't have a table per province, so the drop down list of cities should only show values based on what province I have selected

Provinces

```
ID, Title
1, Ontario
2, Quebec
```

Cities

```
ID, ProvinceID, Title
1, 1, Ottawa
2, 1, Toronto
3, 2, Quebec City
```

I have a 3rd table lets call it, citiesVisited table. This table looks something like this

```
ID, Provivince, City    
1, [Province Drop down based on the entire column], [INSERT ISSUE HERE]
```

If i Change the drop down in province, it should clear out the city drop down value.

The city drop down values are determined on what is selected in the province drop down.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You could try checking out [this link](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)

Comment: @Mistella Unfortunatly I have already looked at that site. The issue, as I mentioned above, i cannot have a table per province. In her case she has a vegetable table and a fruits table.

Comment: This would be fairly easy if you only have a single Province drop down. However, by the sounds of it, you could have a table full of them.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that Sheet 1 is structure like the image below:

[image]

Use this code on sheet 1 change event:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim strID As String, strarr As String
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("B1")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then '<- Lets say that province drop down appears in cell B1.If cell affected then

            Application.EnableEvents = False

                .Range("B2").ClearContents  '<- Clear Cities drop down

                strID = Target.Value '<- Let as assume that province drop down includes provinces ID NOT Title

                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row '<- Find the last row of the Cities table

                For i = 3 To LastRow '<- Loop cities table and get the cities with provincesw choicen

                    If .Range("E" & i).Value = strID Then

                        If strarr = "" Then
                             strarr = .Range("F" & i).Value
                        Else
                             strarr = strarr & "," & .Range("F" & i).Value
                        End If

                    End If

                Next i

                With .Range("B2").Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:=strarr
                End With

            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: are you aware on how to do this without VB?  i for the life of me, cannot figure out why my events arn't firing.  Brand new project. set up just like your photo.

Comment: @AndrewMills if the events aren't firing, there's a few things you can check: 1) That the code is in the sheet1 module, not a general module. 2) That macros are enabled

Answer (score 0):

**If** this is only for 1 drop down, and **not** for multiple rows of drop-downs, then you can use a helper column with `AGGREGATE` and an Array Formula.

`AGGREGATE(15, 7, Range, k` will get you the *k<sup>th</sup>* smallest (`15`) value in `Range` that is not an error or a hidden row (`7`).  So, we need to define `Range` as an array that returns the ID when the Province matches our selection, or an Error (hey, look, the `NA()` function returns an error!) when it does not.

That seems simple enough:  `IF(E$1:E$4=$H$2,D$1:D$4,NA())` will return the value in column D if Column E matches cell H2, or an `#NA!` error if it does not

As for `k`?  Well, we want to start at the top (k = 1) and move down the rows, so we can use `ROW()-1` to start in row 2:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,IF(E$1:E$4=$H$2,D$1:D$4,NA()),ROW()-1)
```

**N.B.** You will have to press <kbd>Ctrk</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula, to ensure that it is an Array Formula (surrounded by `{` and `}`)

Then, we just need a checksum column to tell us how many rows of data to take:  `=--NOT(ISERROR(I:I))` will give us `1` for a row that has a Town in, or `0` for an error row.  We can just `SUM` that column to use in the `OFFSET` to build your Named Range for the drop-down list

[image: Image showing an example of the formula in use, with the data from the Question Post]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without VBA or nasty (IMO) array formulas, but it only works for a single "Province" drop down.

[image]

It centers around the formula in the "City Options", ID Column:

```
MINIFS($G$3:$G$5,$H$3:$H$5,INDEX($D$3:$D$4,MATCH($B$1,$E$3:$E$4,0)),$G$3:$G$5,">"&MAX($K$1:$K1))
```

This gets a list of City IDs for the selected province. It is then wrapped in an `IF` to change zeros into empty strings.

You can then set the data validation list to L3:LXX. That way the list will changes when the selected province changes.